# Connection remains active in RDP farm and profile disks don't load. Where to drop?

Tags: windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services, remote-desktop-gateway

We have a server farm with a Domain Controller, Connection Broker, Gateway and several Terminal Servers.

A user logs in to the RDP generated website and connects to the Gateway. Then starts the RDP session and is redirected to a terminal server.

One of those terminal servers is having an issue that it won't load their profile disk. The user gets an error and is signed in with a temporary profile. If I keep trying this, it may work eventually which makes it strange. But if I now set Allow New Connections to False from Server manager, this user keeps being directed to that same server and now gets an error that logging in is not allowed. After each error the user receives, I log them out, and the TS itself does not show the user being logged in.

I log the user out from the webpage that shows RemoteApp and Desktop logins and log in, but that doesn't matter. I check the RD Gateway manager, but there's no active connection there either.

Still, somehow whenever this user logs in, it is redirected to this server that is not working correctly. If I wait long enough, like half an hour, the connection is eventually dropped and redirection works again.

Meanwhile, other users that did not have issues will work correctly and get redirected to a different server. What am I missing?